# SoapUI change endpoint address

Tags: soap, soapui

I'd like to change the endpoint address, but it's giving me defined values, I mean, only one value  `"/"`. I tried writing there, but it did not work - it is not editable.

How can I change it?

[image]

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Look at the request window and expand the select box with the endpoint address. You should see something like this:

```
/
[edit current...]
[add new endpoint...]
[delete current]
```

You click on `[edit current...]` and you can change the value.

Here is an example using some available web service from *w3schools.com*:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL

[image: Change endpoint address]

Comment: Wow, it's crazy how it was not in a convenient place. Thank you very much. I hope the design will change one day.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, there are 2 ways of changing the endpoint URL

- Select the interface (wsdl entry) that you want to edit and change *Definition URL* value (left bottom pane).
- Close SoapUI, make a backup of your project, open the project's XML file with a good xml editor, search and replace the endpoint string. Save and reopen SoapUI. All the endpoints should show the new value.